# Is it possible to seperate a string into sentences using context?

Tags: python, nlp

Is it possible to seperate string to multiple sentences using NLP in python by string contexts.

Input:

string="Chinese people use social media called weibo in China it is the same as Twitter."

Output:

- Chinese people use social media called weibo in China
- it is the same as Twitter.

Or can we set the boundary of the sentences.

I have tried using tokenization, but using that I can only seperate string by punctuations, whitespace, blanklines etc.

Comment: can you explain it a bit..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your example can be splitted in different places still giving a valid sentences.

```
string="Chinese people use social media called weibo in China it is the same as Twitter."
```

- Chinese people use social media
- Chinese people use social media called weibo.
- Social media called weibo in China is the same as Twitter.
- weibo in China is the same as Twitter
- China is the same as Twitter

and so on ...

There's no one best split for given example so your algorithm should generate all valid possibilities.

Comment: Can you tell me how to seperate this string into multiple valid sentences?

Comment: @AjeetSingh why have you ticked this as an accepted answer and then commented to the effect that it doesn't answer your question??

Comment: Because machine cannot specifically tell what we are thinking or what we are expecting. We have to teach machine what we are expecting, so it can give us nearest output.

Comment: @AjeetSingh: sorry, I can't help you here. I just pointed out the ambiguity of your problem you should be aware of.

Answer (score 0):

Look up context free grammars, then define one for the English language, then parse using a package such as http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/.

See for example http://www.nltk.org/book/ch08.html. Actually, http://www.nltk.org/ is probably a great resource to start from.

Comment: Pyparsing is no longer hosted on wikispaces.com. Go to https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing